# remove the first several elements from a list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list that is very large 1000+ and I am wanting to remove the first 319 elements from the list. 
I have tried

```
 for i in range(0,320):
     list1.pop(i)
```

but this doesn't work however when I do `list1.pop(0)` separately it does remove an element
How am i able to remove the first 319 elements

Comment: If you find yourself wanting to delete stuff from the beginning of a list, it's often better to use a [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.deque) instead because it doesn't need to shift the values on every deletion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `del` on a slice:

```
del list1[:319]
```

This will remove elements 0 - 318 (so a total of 319 elements) in one go.

Comment: I would have been faster if I had typed enough characters to pass the minimal length filter to start with..

Answer (score 2):

Use slicing syntax:

```
del list1[0:319]
```

By the way, calling `list1.pop` repeatedly does not work because the items are reindexed after each deletion. So, when you delete the first item, the *next* item (that was the second one) becomes the first. If you really want to use `pop` in a loop, you have to call `list1.pop(0)` 319 times - but that's gonna be terribly inefficient.